# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver while using ORACLE database in Yii

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, yii

Hi I am trying to connect Yii application with oracle. In my extensions folder

I have the files

```
php_pdo_oci.dll
php_oci8.dll
```

and configuration in php like

```
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

after this I have restarted apache

and when I look `phpinfo()` , it is not showing the `pdo_oci` driver installed

[image]
config in main.php

```
'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/demodb',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

what would be the mistake?

Comment: Are you sure that you're checking the correct config? can you show its local path?

Comment: @alexk984 yes 'C:\php' because when i disable extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll i can able to see the change in PDO drivers which i showed in above image!

Comment: Please post your config for the DB component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was done by https://github.com/yjeroen/oci8Pdo extension.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's probably your double slash before the host info (//) that is the problem. If you make it look more like this does it fix your issue?

```
//Database component
'db'=>array
(
    'class'=>'CDbConnection',
'connectionString'=>'oci:dbname=10.10.4.106:1521/orcl',
    'charset'=>'UTF8'
),
```

Comment: while loading 'oci' it checks for drivers. after that only it will go to check the dbname and all